# Combobox selected value foregournd color XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, selecteditem, foreground

I want to change the foregournd color for the selected value to White in my Combobox. Is there any way to perform the desire action. 
Cheers
Whynottshirt

[image: ComboBox]

Style of my ComboBox:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Kororder.ApplicationDesign.Styles.MyCombo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Color x:Key="GrayColor_">#FF928B81</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightGrayColor_">#FFC3C3C3</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightLightGrayColor_">#FFF1F1F1</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayColor" Color="{StaticResource GrayColor_}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightGrayColor_}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightLightGrayColor" Color="{StaticResource LightLightGrayColor_}"/>

<Color x:Key="BlueColor_">#0073b0</Color>
<Color x:Key="DarkBlueColor_">#FF004165</Color>
<Color x:Key="LightBlueColor_">#FFa4ddfa</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColor" Color="{StaticResource BlueColor_}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource DarkBlueColor_}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlueColor" Color="{StaticResource LightBlueColor_}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundWhite" Color="White"/>


<Style x:Key="LightGrayBox" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />
</Style>


<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.6" Fill="{StaticResource GrayColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayBox}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GrayColor}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource GrayColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonActive" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="1" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>



<Style x:Key="StandardComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid GotFocus="OnGotFocus">
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                             CaretBrush="{DynamicResource ForegroundWhite}"
                             Style="{x:Null}" 
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                             Focusable="True" 
                             Background="Transparent" 
                             Foreground="{StaticResource Foreground}" 
                             Visibility="Hidden" 
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup VerticalOffset="-1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="200">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Style="{DynamicResource LightGrayBox}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource GrayColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ToggleButton" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonActive}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueColor}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Problem Solved:

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=mQ9u

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the msdn site and get the default control template for the combobox. After that you use it in your project and change it depending on your needs. Here: [ComboBox ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Either that or use Expression Blend

Comment: The following image is a result of my xaml.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/L8jpj.png

Its bit difficult to achieve the desire result out of your MSDN template.



MY XAML CODE:
http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=yWl7a

Comment: in the <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" (...) part, change your foregroung value from "{StaticResource Foreground}" to "White", I think that's what you want

Comment: The text changes its color to white. And on LostFocus both Background and Foreground are white :) I want White Foreground on Onfocus but Black on Lost focus.

Comment: Did you try to use Expression Blend? That's a pretty cool tool to edit control styles! I would have to go through the xaml in a more detailed way to get the changes you pretend as I'm quite new to all these as well ;)

Comment: Yeah I m using Blend too. Unfortunatly no solution found there too. Anyways thanks for your help :)